# While fitting my own regression with GD the kernel appears to have died

Tags: python, class, jupyter-notebook, kernel, linear-regression

I made my linear regression class with gradient descent: `class LinearReg(BaseEstimator)`.

When I try to iterate over parameters in a loop, I get this incomprehensible error:

```
for eta in [1e-1, 1e-3, 2e-2, 3e-2, 5e-2]:
    gd_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
                            ('ohe_and_scaling', column_transformer),
                            ('regression', LinearReg(gd_type='full', max_iter=6666, eta=eta))
                          ])
    
    model = gd_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print(f'eta = {eta}')
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print('Test MSE = %.4f' % mse(y_pred, y_test))
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print('Test R2 = %.4f' % r2(y_pred, y_test))
    print('-----')
```

**`The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.`**

At the same time, at the previous stage, when I ran it once, everything was fine:

```
%%time
model = gd_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print('Test MSE = %.4f' % mse(y_pred, y_test))
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print('Test R2 = %.4f' % r2(y_pred, y_test))
print('-----')
```

```
Test MSE = 0.6507
Test R2 = -0.0334
-----
CPU times: user 3min 30s, sys: 41.2 s, total: 4min 11s
Wall time: 4min 31s
```

P.S. `pip install -U numpy` doesn't help. Mb my macbook is weak?

---

```
X_train.info()
```

```
Data columns (total 7 columns):
year_day          1021050 non-null int64
weekday           1021050 non-null int64
hour              1021050 non-null int64
month             1021050 non-null int64
blizzard          1021050 non-null int64
summer_anomaly    1021050 non-null int64
const             1021050 non-null int64

memory usage: 62.3 MB
```